# I would like to know how to get the color code of a certain point

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

・Purpose
I want to change the color of the padding to match the color of a particular point in the app.

[image]

Because I want to make the statesbar change color.

・What I want
Color code for a specific point
If I scroll down and come to the blue part of the image at a specific point, I want to get the blue color code.

===
I have done quite a bit of research and have found no information on how to do that.
Therefore, I would like to know.

The screen in the screenshot is a webView.
I would like to be able to get the color code for a specific point so I can change the color on the webView screen and on the widget.

Comment: I did could not find answer .